# HasManyThrough with extrafield

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

I have a relation:

```
Class Championship extends Model{

 public function fights()
 {
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Fight::class, Tree::class);
 }

}
```

When I do :

```
$championship->fights,
```

I get the fight Collection I need.

But I would also need to group them by area, and area belongs to Tree ( $tree->area ).

Is it posible to get this relation with an extra field from Tree????

Or should I add area field in Fight table ( but it sounds like data duplication )

Comment: Championship has one or many Trees?

Comment: one championship has one tree!

Comment: And one Tree has many areas?

Comment: @AlexLukinov areas is a field, not an entity

Comment: no, area is just a field, an integer inside tree

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro It makes more sense for me that each fight has its area, unless if all the fights of the same championship are played in the same area. And in that case, just put the `area` field in the championship table.

Comment: how looks table for Tree model?

Comment: @GerardReches in ChampionshipSettings, user defined areas quantity : 1, 2, 4, so, it could change. I could put it in Fight, but I also need it in Tree, so, should I duplicate data?

Comment: @AlexLukinov id, user1, user2 ,user3, area, order, timestamps

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro You could put it in championship, not in tree.

Comment: nop, inside tree, I have all my groups of fights, that belongs to an area. A championship can be played in several areas